# To show $f(x)$ is discontinuous at every point

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1  ,& \text {$x$ is rational} \\
0 , &  \text{$x$ is irrational}\\
\end{cases}$$
How do I show this function is discontinuous at every point. How to think about it intuitively.  Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: See if you can find two sequences of numbers approaching an arbitrary point $x_0$ where the limits don't agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that both sets $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R-Q}$ are dense in $\mathbb{R}$ which means that for any point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, and any open interval $(-a+x_0,a+x_0)$ always contains some rational and irrational number. So for $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and any $\delta > 0$, and any $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $x_0'\in (x_0-\delta, x_0 + \delta)$ such that one is rational and the other is irrational number. Thus $|f(x_0) - f(x_0')| = 1 > \dfrac{1}{2}$. This means $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: You have used Cauchy Criteria for existence of finite limits ? Thanks

Comment: I think so Sophie.

Comment: No problem, any time Sophie.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: In every interval with the centre $x_0$ there are rational and irrational numbers and values of $f$ on them are different. Hence we have to sequences tending to 0 (if the lengths of intervals are, say, $1/n$) such that values on them tend either to 1 or to 0.

Comment: @JMoravitz Certainly. Thank you!

Comment: it means we cannot find a intervel where value of function is going close to a number .But how to prove it .Thanks

Comment: @SophieClad Is the extended version of my hint more clear?

Comment: I have unerstood it intuitively but am not exactly sure how to prove it ?

Comment: @SophieClad You should  already know Heine's definition of continuity and the fact, that rationals and irrationals are dense in every interval. Then there is a standard, suggested, procedure: finding two sequences tending to $x_0$ with values tending to different constants.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ for two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ (which will be $\mathbb{R}$ in this case).

To check continuity at a point $c \in X$, it is sufficient to check that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow c} f(x) = f(c)$.

Does this hold in this case?  Remember that the rational numbers are dense in $\mathbb{R}$.